# Extraer fecha dentro de una cadena de texto SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente cadena: `Un texto cualquiera 22/12/2016 fin texto`

Estoy intentando obtener la posición de `22/12/2016` con la función PATINDEX:

`SELECT PATINDEX('__/__/____', 'Un texto cualquiera 22/12/2016 fin texto');`

Pero la función me devuelve 0, ¿Sabéis que estoy haciendo mal?

La barra baja `_` según el enlace de microsoft es para un caracter. [Patrones](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que falta el caracter `%`

```
SELECT PATINDEX('__/__/____', 'Un texto cualquiera 22/12/2016 fin texto');
```

Este pattern solo seria valido para esta cadena `'22/12/2016'` porque no tiene forma de identificar varios caracteres.

Si lo cambiamos por

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%__/__/____%', 'Un texto cualquiera 22/12/2016 fin texto');
```

Ya deberia funcionar

Answer (score 6):

Saludos [nachfren](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6564/nachfren), considerando que el formato de las fechas es **dd/mm/aaaa** , esto te será de utilidad:

```
declare @cadenaDeTexto varchar(100)
set @cadenaDeTexto = 'Un texto cualquiera 22/12/2016 fin texto'

select substring(@cadenaDeTexto,
            patindex('%[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @cadenaDeTexto),
            10) as "Fecha Extraida"
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Fecha Extraida
22/12/2016
```

El presente código no funcionará si el formato cambia como **d/m/aaaa** o **dd/m/aaaa** o **d/mm/aaaa**. Espero me haya dejado entender, caso contrario, dale a los comentarios y vemos cómo te apoyamos hermano :D